# buscar en un for en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Que tal, tengo este array:

[image: total]

la cual corresponde al total de la compra según el pedido, en este caso
mediante un for como puedo llegar a ese valor:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {

     var totaldesayuno = total[i].totaldesayuno;
     var totalcafe = total[i].totalcafe;
     var totalsandwich = total[i].totalsandwich;
     var totaldulce = total[i].totaldulce;

  }
```

necesito preguntar cual es el que tiene el valor para poder mostrarlo en front con `$scope`

Comment: recorre los valores en total[i] y has un if para comprobar cual no es nulo

Answer (score 0):

Recorre cada valor en `total[i]` y crea una condición para comprobar cual no es nulo (Esto solo funciona si en todos los casos solo 1 item obtendrá el valor)

```
forEach (total[i], function(value, key))
    if (value != null)
        return value;
```

Esto debajo de tu forloop, en `key` tienes el nombre del objeto (totaldesayuno, totalcafe, etc...) no se angularJs, pero esto debe funcionar. No seria return value, usarias eso de scope, o lo que sea, pero la lógica es como te lo puse, has tu modificaciones y espero te funcione.